# Finding a small prime ideal above an ideal

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $I$ be an ideal of $\mathbb C[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. Define the $g$-degree of $I$ as the minimal transcendence degree (over $\mathbb C$) of a field generated by a generating subset of $I$.

Let $I$ be any ideal of $g$-degree $k$.

> > Is $I$ contained in a prime ideal of $g$-degree $k$?

**yes** if $I$ is 1-generated.

Comment: I would think you would want to consider the transcendence degree of the field generated by a set of generators for $I$, rather than require that the set of generators be algebraically independent.  For instance, for an ideal like $I=(x^2,xy,y^2)\subset\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ I suspect that there does not exist any algebraically independent generating subset at all.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks again